# typescript for-loop with promise not working

Tags: typescript, for-loop, asynchronous, promise, hyperledger-composer

I have a for-loop, which (in each iteration) sends a transaction to the blockchain. For some reason, this loop does not work. Only one of the the patients is processed.

Here's the loop:

```
for (let patient of this.allPatients) {

        let patientString = 'org.hospital.carefabric.Patient#' + client.id;
        let drugString = 'org.hospital.carefabric.Drug#' + this.drugId;

        this.transaction = {
         $class:'org.hospital.carefabric.AddDrugsToPatient',
          'patient': patientString,
          'newDrugs': [drugString],
          'timestamp': new Date().getTime()
        };

        return this.addDrugsToPatientService.addTransaction(this.transaction)
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => {
          this.errorMessage = null;
        })
        .catch((error) => {  
            this.errorMessage = error;       
        });

}
```

I guess this has sth to do with the promise. But I just can't see what the problem is.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the promise. The issue here is that you have a `return` statement inside your loop, which means the loop executes one time, then the function returns, which prevents further iteration.

Comment: you can use a this.allPatients.forEach method and then the return statement wont short circuit the loop. If you want to wait for all of those promises to finish so you can do an action afterwards instead of returning it you can push them into an array and use a Promise.all on that.

Comment: Do you need the transactions to operate in serial, or can they be in parallel? To execute in parallel, I would `.map` the patients to promises then `await Promise.all(transactionPromises)`. If each transaction should wait until the previous one is finished, `await` the promise which will pause the loop.

Comment: note you will also run into trouble with non-deterministic code, when you do fix it ; this line `'timestamp': new Date().getTime()` could/will be evaluated differently when the transaction proposals are simulated by endorsing peers (don't believe they'll get the same result).

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony: tanks you for your comment ... you mean the endorsing peer and the committing peer would get different time stamps for the same transaction? If so, why would that be a problem?

Comment: Another possible reason of the issue is that you don't use `patient` in your service call; `this.transaction` would be formed with the same data (except `timestamp`) per each iteration.